# React Element is changing from controlled to uncontrolled and vice versa error explanation

Tags: reactjs, input

This error is common for beginners in react. And there are many solutions on stack overflow.

But what I want to ask is that, what is the problem with changing a field from controlled to uncontrolled. What if I want to set the value of input to `null` and then I want to assign a value after that and vice versa. Why is this is an error in the first place.

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/570) helps

Comment: the link describes a solution to the problem. I definitely know the source of the problem and its solution. What I want to know is, what's wrong with switching an element between controlled and uncontrolled.